Telegram Post Python Script: Trying Recode from asyncio to trio
Ok, so I was successfully running a TG script on Win/python 3.12.
But I want to run the TG script on a Pi box, python 3.11.    The script completes, but hangs at End of Main().  There are other people having same problem.  I was using the "newer" asyncio.run() lib method.
I saw a post about using TRIO instead, so trying it out.
HOWEVER, Trio seems to be geared towards "concurrent tasking".... Something I don't need re Telegram.
The ONLY functions I'm calling TG for are 1)  Connecting  2)  Posting.   Connecting 1x, Posting 2x in same script.
##### Trade Ogre  Exch  ####
Sell_Ladder = Trade_Ogre_Orders ()

if Sell_Ladder :

    if globals()['TGConn_Flag'] == 0 :
        TelegramConn = trio.run (SendMsg_CCX.Start_Telegram_Client())

        globals()['TGConn_Flag'] = 1

        trio.run (SendMsg_CCX.Post_2_Telegram ('TradeOgre', Sell_Ladder, TelegramConn))

The above functions/procedures should be fine for me.... Connecting, then Sending Post.
However Trio wants me to call min 2 functions.
If I do a trio.run() with BOTH functions, then Python can't find "TelegramConn".....
Am I using Trio incorrectly.... Do I need to use asyncio with Telegram?... & revert to the older method of asyncio :   asyncio.run_until_completed()
